# Create variable with multiple conditions on different variables with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a variable that allows me to differentiate between items in `my_code` with negative and positive `rate` in `year == 2020`. So that is in year 2020 rate goes negative, my new variable is 1 for all the years. So far I have used `mutate` with `if_else` that takes on values `1` if `rate` in 2020 is < 0 and 0 otherwise, but it only assigns
`1` to the very year the rate is negative and not to the whole `my_id` series:

```
mydt %>% mutate(rate.sign = mutate( if_else (year == 2020 & rate < 0, 1 , 0)))
```

How can I fix that?

```
   id_code variable  year  rate my_id     new.var
     <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     233 x         1950 NA        1    0
 2     233 x         1955  2.97     1    0
 3     233 x         1960  2.98     1    0
 4     233 x         1965  1.2      1    0
 5     233 x         1970  2.01     1    0
 6     233 x         1975  2.39     1    0
 7     233 x         1980  2.28     1    0
 8     233 x         1985  0.66     1    0
 9     233 x         1990  0.66     1    0
10     233 x         1995  1.04     1    0
...
15     233 x         2020  0.81     1    0
18     233 x         1950  3.37     2    1
...                
30     233 x         2010 -0.78     2    1
31     233 x         2015 -0.82     2    1
32     233 x         2020 -0.75     2    1
33     233 x         2025 -0.45     2    1
34     233 x         2030 -0.62     2    1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Below is a simplified dataset:

```
mydt = structure(list(id_code = c(233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 233, 
233), 
variable = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
"x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"), 
year = c(1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030, 1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030), 
rate = c(NA, 2.97, 2.98, 1.20, 2.01, 2.39, 2.28, 0.66, 0.66, 1.04, 0.96, 0.87, 0.86, 0.85, 0.81, 0.38, 0.58, 3.37, 2.93, 0, 2.02, 1.80, 2.37, 0, 0.72, 0.71, 1.33, 0.92, 1.06, -0.78, -0.82, -0.75, -0.45, -0.62), 
my_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), 
class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -34L), groups = structure(list( id_code = 233, variable = "x", .rows = structure(list(1:34), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",  "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a `logical` variable, that will be `TRUE` if *any* row in which `year == 2000` also has a `rate < 0`, within each group of rows with the same `my_id`.

```
mydt %>%
group_by(my_id) %>%
mutate(neg.y2k = any(year == 2000 & rate < 0))
```

Comment: It seems to set everything to `TRUE`

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted: "So that is in year 2020 rate goes negative, my new variable is 1 for all the years".

Comment: All years within the `my_id` range, I tried it and it sets to TRUE also those `my_id` that do not have a negative `rate` in 2020

Comment: Just use `group_by(my_id)` before adding the variable

Comment: Great! works as it should now